# Center a flex item when it is an only child

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container that can contain one or more elements.

If there is more than one element I want to justify content using space-between

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

If there is only one element I want it to be centered.

Example [codepen](https://codepen.io/haki/pen/prpWvb?editors=1100)

Is this possible using only CSS?

Comment: why do you use `space-between` and not `center`?

Comment: If there is more than one element I want it to use space-between. Only if there is one element is want it to be centered.

Comment: so why not giving a class to where there's only one element and give `justify-content: center;` to it?

Comment: you may also consider using `space-around`

Comment: space-around will not attach the elements to the end/start of the container when there is more than one element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The flexbox specification makes this possible.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a:only-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <a>item 1</a>
  <a>item 2</a>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <a>item 1</a>
</div>
```

From the spec:

> [**8.1. Aligning with `auto`
>   margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
>   positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.

So, basically, use `justify-content` on the parent and an auto margin on the child.

Per the rule above, the auto margin takes precedence when the `only-child` selector applies.

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    & > *:only-child {
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin: auto` to your item. Hope it is what you are looking for.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <a>item 1</a>
  <a>item 2</a>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <a>item 1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, it's similar to setting justify-content: space-around. Notice how when there are more than one item it is centered and not justified to the end of the container.